# Get the number of users that belong to a group and the number of orders that belong to the group through its users

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `user_groups` table, a `users` table and an `orders` table.

The relationship between them is this: `users.group_id`, `orders.user_id`.

I'm trying to get the amount of users that belong to each group, and the amount of orders that belong to each group through its users.

My code:

```
select user_groups.*, count(users.id) as user_count, count(orders.id) as order_count

from user_groups

left join users on user_groups.id=users.group_id
left join orders on users.id=orders.user_id

group by user_groups.id
```

Expected output:

```
id | user_count | order_count
1  | 5          | 67
2  | 1          | 1
```

Actual output:

[image]

**The amount of orders should be 5, not 71:**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `count(distinct)`:

```
select ug.*, count(distinct u.id) as user_count, count(distinct o.id) as order_count    
from user_groups ug left join
     users u
     on ug.id = u.group_id left join
     orders o
     on u.id = o.user_id
group by ug.id;
```

`count(id)` counts the number of non-`NULL` values.  You apparently want to count the number of *different* values, which is what `distinct` does.

Comment: Thank you! I will accept this answer in 11 minutes - when SO lets me. Could you please add a short explanation of how `distinct` works here?